# Git changes to a visual studio .csproj file don't reflect as changes to the origin. Why?

Tags: git, visual-studio

1. On master branch, I did a `git pull` to get the latest changes to master
2. Then I did `git checkout -b new_branch`
3. On this branch I deleted a few lines to a .csproj file
4. The diff showed the correct change, i.e.

`zach@DESKTOP...:<path>$ git diff master`, showed:

```
diff --git a/<path>.csproj
index 58a5da4..8062eb5 100644
--- a/<path>.csproj
+++ b/<path>.csproj
@@ -79,9 +79,6 @@
     <None Include="App.config">
       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
     </None>
-    <None Include="env-config.json">
-      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
-    </None>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="<path>.csproj">
```

5. Then I ran `git add .`
6. Then I ran `git commit -m "new changes added"`
7. Then I ran `git push`

At this point I expected to be prompted to `--set-upstream` a path. But instead I got back a message that said everything was up-to-date.

Looking at the source on Bitbucket, neither the new branch with the recently committed change, nor the change itself in the master branch appeared.

***Why is this?***

I should note that I'm using the Windows 10 implementation of bash (i.e. a virtualized Ubuntu 14.04 machine), but changes to regular source code seem to work fine.

I'm also running Windows 10 Home on an Apple by Bootcamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the
>    argument, branch.*.remote configuration for the current
>   branch is
>          consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to origin.
>
> When the command line does not specify what to push with ... arguments or --all, --mirror, --tags options, the command
>   finds the default
>           by consulting remote.*.push configuration, and if it is not found, honors push.default configuration to decide what to push
>   (See git-
>          config(1) for the meaning of push.default).
>
> When neither the command-line nor the configuration specify what to push, the default behavior is used, which corresponds to the
>   simple value for
>          push.default: the current branch is pushed to the corresponding upstream branch, but as a safety measure, the push is aborted if the
>   upstream branch
>          does not have the same name as the local one.

This means, when the new created branch not already exists and is the current one for the remote, that `the push is aborted`

Comment: Does it fail silently?

Comment: Yes. it does fail silently, with the old `--set-upstream` message deprecated. Once i explicitly did `-u origin <branch>`, the push worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your gitignore file to be sure it's not ignoring csproj files?

If it's there you'll want to remove it, a csproj file should definitely go to the repository.

Comment: I definitely don't have .csproj in the .gitignore. if I did, I would not see changes to .csproj files